# Sklearn elastic-net logistic regression (SGDClassifier) does not return a probability

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression

In sklearn, when using SGDCLassifier for elastic-net logistic regression, the `predict_proba` function returns the same thing as the `predict` function.

AKA the code below (with `X` and `y` the predictors and binary label respectively) returns `True`:

```
EN = sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier(loss='log', penalty='elasticnet',
                                        alpha=0.0001, l1_ratio=0.15)
EN.fit(X[train], y[train])
numpy.all(EN.predict(X[test]) == EN.predict_proba(X[test])[:,1])
```

How to obtain probability values?

Comment: What version of sklearn do you have ?

Comment: sklearn.__version__: 0.18

Comment: Can you update to 0.18.2 and see if the problem persists ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the sklearn version is the problem. You need to upgrade to 0.18.2.

**Example using iris data:**

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear import model.SGDClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy
import sklearn

data = load_iris()
x = data.data
y = data.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)

EN = SGDClassifier(loss='log', penalty='elasticnet', alpha=0.0001, l1_ratio=0.15)

EN.fit(X_train, y_train)

numpy.all(EN.predict(X_test) == EN.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])
sklearn.__version__
```

**Result**

```
False

'0.18.2'
```

So with sklearn 0.18.2 it works fine.

Comment: I will check soon and get back to you, thanks a lot!

Comment: @michael sure. let me know if you solved your problem

Comment: The [predict_proba](http://scikit-learn.org/0.17/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.predict_proba) method is also present in version 0.17 and 0.18. So I doubt if thats a problem. @michael can you post the complete code and data.

Comment: @VivekKumar  yes it is also in 0.17 but it could be a bug

Comment: @sera It seems your example works even with version 0.18 and the problem comes from the fact that the probabilities became 0 and 1 due to limitations of machine precision. Even in your example you can see that the probabilities are essentially 0 and 1.